# Book like page numbering in LibreOffice

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice

How can I achieve the following goals using LibreOffice Writer?

The first few pages should be numbered in Roman numbers (like i, ii, iii, iv, ...), but the very first page number should be hidden, second page should start with ii.

Other pages should be numbered in Arabic numbers (like 1, 2, 3...), starting from 1.

Page numbers should be in the footer.

[I am using LibreOffice V 4.2.2.1 on OS X Mavericks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be achieved without using Master Documents using the latest versions of LibreOffice Writter. (tested on V4.2)

Create two types of page style (call them Roman style and Arabic style or whatever you like) using `Format > Styles & Formatting > Page > right click on a style & choose New Style`.

Now apply the Roman style to all pages, and all your page numbers will be in Roman numbers.

Now configure the title page using `Format > Title page`. Now your title page will not have the page number displayed like we expect.

Now go to the page where you want to start Arabic numbers. `Right click > Paragraph > Text Flow > Tic Insert, Tic With Style, choose Arabic Style and Page Number as 1.`

Now you are finished!

Answer (score 2):

The key word is "Master Documents" - that is a possibility add the breaks in the page numbering and change the style of it.
Take a look at this article please, HTH: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Recommended_method

Comment: The footer in the subdocument does not appear after it has been inserted into the master document. The footer from the master document   takes dominant. Therefore subdocument page numbers (which are in the footer) vanishes. Tested with LibreOffice only.

Comment: Seems to be a bug :(